# Equivalent PyQt code for C++ Qt Snippet

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, code-translation

I'm using PyQt and understand enough OOP to get by comfortably in Python. However, the documentation and useful forum posts are all in C++. I know that the best route would probably be to just re-learn C++. I'm trying but It's taking a long time to sift through tutorials and find the information that I need, mostly because I don't understand enough of the terminology to know where to look.

In a particular forum [post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20332-QGraphicsTextItem-and-text-cursor-position-via-QPoint?p=234213#post234213) there is a section in a method of a class implementation that reads:

```
    void SetTextInteraction(bool on, bool selectAll = false)
{
    if(on && textInteractionFlags() == Qt::NoTextInteraction)
    {
        // switch on editor mode:
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
        // manually do what a mouse click would do else:
        setFocus(Qt::MouseFocusReason); // this gives the item keyboard focus
        setSelected(true); // this ensures that itemChange() gets called when we click out of the item
        if(selectAll) // option to select the whole text (e.g. after creation of the TextItem)
        {
            QTextCursor c = textCursor();
            c.select(QTextCursor::Document);
            setTextCursor(c);
        }
    }
    else if(!on && textInteractionFlags() == Qt::TextEditorInteraction)
    {
        // turn off editor mode:
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
        // deselect text (else it keeps gray shade):
        QTextCursor c = this->textCursor();
        c.clearSelection();
        this->setTextCursor(c);
        clearFocus();
    }
}
```

The part I don't understand is here:

```
QTextCursor c = textCursor();
c.select(QTextCursor::Document);
setTextCursor(c);
```

What would be the equivalent Python code for this specific section? For some reason I thought the first line might be `c = QTextCursor.textCursor()` in that result of the method `textCursor` from the `QTextCursor` class is being assigned to `c`, but it seems that there is no `textCursor` method. Also I'm having trouble understanding what is going on here:

```
 QTextCursor c = this->textCursor();
 c.clearSelection();
 this->setTextCursor(c);
```

An explanation of what is going on in words would be useful as this would help with the terminology bit. A recommendation on some resources to go through to understand these specific pieces of code would be appreciated as well.

Comment: this in C++ -> self in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Python and PyQt is rusty, but here's a translation with possible small errors in syntax:

```
def SetTextInteraction(self, on, selectAll):
    if on and self.textInteractionFlags() == Qt.NoTextInteraction:
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.setFocus(Qt.MouseFocusReason)
        self.setSelected(True) 
        if selectAll:
            c = self.textCursor()
            c.select(QTextCursor.Document)
            self.setTextCursor(c)
    elif not on and self.textInteractionFlags() == Qt.TextEditorInteraction:
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        c = self.textCursor()
        c.clearSelection()
        self.setTextCursor(c)
        self.clearFocus()
```

There are two reasons you're confused about what's happening in the code you linked to:

1. C++ handles implicit scope resolution at compile time; Python requires explicit declarations. Local scope (the member function) is checked first, then the surrounding class, then (I believe) the local translation unit/local non-member functions, and finally up the namespace/scope heirarchy until it finds the function or variable being referenced.

   `textCursor` is a member function of the parent class for `TextItem`. Calling `textCursor()` is the same as calling `this->textCursor()`, which in Python would be `self.textCursor()`.
2. The code provided intermingles explicit usage of `this` with implicit calls. Using `this` where not necessary is considered bad form in C++ and made it appear as if `textCursor()` is not the same as `this->textCursor()`. Hopefully in reading through the Python version I provided, you'll see there is no difference.

**Resources for the future**
The [C++ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info) has great links to FAQs on C++. I recommend a stroll through the [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/faq). You'll learn things you didn't expect you needed to know and things you didn't know were not clear will be clarified. There is also [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on SO.

For PyQt development, Mark Summerfield's [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354187) is a great reference with working code.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now. It was a bit confusing to see the `this` being used in one line and not the other. I'm hoping from this answer and the resources you've recommended that I can get through more of the C++ Qt examples.

Comment: One small edit. `elif not on and textInteractionFlags()` should be `elif not on and self.textInteractionFlags()`

Comment: I recommend Mark Summerfield's Qt and PyQt books for working code examples and explanations. Since he's both a Qt and PyQt developer, his work is particularly appealing.

Comment: Good call. I downloaded his book, "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt" yesterday and it is really great.

Answer (score 2):

`SetTextInteraction` in the original code is a method of a subclass of `QGraphicsTextItem`, and `textCursor()` method is inherited from `QGraphicsTextItem`. Translation to PyQt is literal:

```
class TextItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(TextItem, self).__init__(parent)

  def test(self):
    c = self.textCursor()
    c.clearSelection()
    self.setTextCursor(c)
```

In this piece of code we get a cursor object using `QGraphicsTextItem::textCursor`, modify it and set it using `QGraphicsTextItem::setTextCursor` to apply the changes.

Comment: Great to know that `SetTextInteraction` is being overriden here. I would have not know otherwise considering how it is used in the post I like.

Comment: `SetTextInteraction` is not being overriden because there is no such method in the base class. It's just a new method.